# Please inform me how to use variables as the attribute value in CSS

Tags: css, pug

I'm using PUG.

I entered 10 on the variable h.

I'd like to use the h as a property of element named item.

```
- var h=10
doctype html
html
    head
        style.
            .item {height: hpx;}
    body
        .item Hello!
```

Of course it didn't work.T.T

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html):

```
- var h=10
doctype html
html
    head
        style.
            .item {height: #{h}px;}
    body
        .item Hello!
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code :

In HTML file:

```
html
 head
    style.
        .item { height: var(--h);color: var(--color); }

 body
    .item Hello!
```

In CSS file:

```
:root {
  --h: 10px;
  --color: red; 
}
```

Hope it's work well for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I didn't know it, but it helped me a lot.